# How to read contents of a Google Doc from the script of a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, authorization, google-docs

I am trying to use Google App Script (GAS) here. I have a `code.gs` attached with my sheet. I am fetching values and sending else where. In one particular column of the sheet, I have URLs to a Google Doc, which contains additional information.

So if I am to read N rows, I have to read contents of N respective Google Docs. Is there some way for me to open and read from these Google docs, within the `code.gs` that is attached to the sheet?

**EDIT:**

I figured out that using [DocumentApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app) class,  I can read the contents of the google doc. The following code worked out fine for me.

```
function myFunction() {      
  var doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/document/<ID>");
  var body = doc.getBody();
  // I had a table in all the docs. They are uniform in structure.
  var table= body.getTables()[0];
  // My data was stored in the 10th row.
  var row = t.getRow(10);
  var res = row.getText();

  Logger.log(res);

}
```

Now I have hit the next bumper. The owner of Google Sheet is SAM. All Google Docs that are owned by SAM can be read by the above code. Some of them are not owned by SAM. These can't be read. The error I get is `Execution failed: Action not allowed` for the line `doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl(...)` . Is there some way to get around this authorization issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a security restriction. SAM will only be able to read those documents which are either owned by him or are shared with him. So those documents which are not owned by SAM must be **shared** with him by the actual owner of the documents.

Comment: Can we assume the script is running as someone with view or edit or owner rights?